# How to plot function against another function?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot V(z) against phi(z). I tried to used `ParametricPlot`
but that didn't answer.

```
V[Z_] := (2838.24)*(4 - (0.3 Z)/(1 + Z)) (1 + Z)^0.3 Exp[-0.3 Z/(1 + Z)];

phi[Z_] := 0.1 +NIntegrate[(0.1 (x/(x+ 1)) (1 + x)^0.3 Exp[(-0.3 x)/(1 +x)])^(1/4)/
   (72 (1 + x) (0.27 (1 + x)^3 + 0.73 (1 + x)^0.3 Exp[(-0.3 x)/(1 + x)])^(1/2)), {x, 0, Z}];

ParametricPlot[{V[z], phi[z]}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

Please tell me where is my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: When you define a function, you should use `V[Z_]:=` instead of `V(Z):=`. Also when you plot them, `z` and `Z` should be consistent.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html

Comment: Dear,  xslittlegrass this is a type mistake only there . in my code it's correct  I'm sorry for that

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot[{V[z], 100000*phi[z]}, {z, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
V[Z_] := (2838.24)*(4 - (0.3 Z)/(1 + Z)) (1 + 
      Z)^0.3 Exp[-0.3 Z/(1 + Z)];
phi[Z_] := 
  0.1 + NIntegrate[(0.1 (x/(x + 1)) (1 + 
           x)^0.3 Exp[(-0.3 x)/(1 + x)])^(1/
        4)/(72 (1 + 
         x) (0.27 (1 + x)^3 + 
          0.73 (1 + x)^0.3 Exp[(-0.3 x)/(1 + x)])^(1/2)), {x, 0, Z}];
ParametricPlot[{V[z], phi[z]}, {z, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]